# How archive command works in postgres

Tags: postgresql, replication

Just wondering how does this postgres wal archive command works in replication:

```
rsync -z -a --contimeout=120 --partial-dir=.rsync-partial %p db-slave.sr1.net::primary-wal-archive-share/%f
```

what does this `%p` and `%f` mean here?

Answer (score 1):

from [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-ARCHIVE-COMMAND):

> The local shell command to execute to archive a completed WAL file
>   segment. **Any %p in the string is replaced by the path name of the file
>   to archive, and any %f is replaced by only the file name**. (The path
>   name is relative to the working directory of the server, i.e., the
>   cluster's data directory.) Use %% to embed an actual % character in
>   the command. It is important for the command to return a zero exit
>   status only if it succeeds

(emphasis mine)

Also take a look at [setting WAL archiving](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-ARCHIVING-WAL)

Comment: What if the data directory contain multiple wal files? postgres will assign latest wal as %f?

Comment: Also, if i want to ship this wal file to a different server on a different network after the first rsync, will %f  stay same through out all rsync runs?

Comment: one shared folder. master writes to it (archive_command), slaves read from it (restore_command in recovery.conf)

Comment: Will the following archive command work or is it recommended?

rsync -z -a --contimeout=120 %p db-slave.sr1.net::primary-wal-archive-share/%f  &&  upload.sh %p 

Given last upload.sh script uploads my data dir to another server and creates new data/pg_xlog dir

Comment: Dino: is you intent to send the WAL archives to more than one place, i.e. an archive server and a hot standby server?

Comment: Yes @CraigRinger